# clear state of redux when navigating to different route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have this in my login.js, I tried to use wrong password to trigger it.

`{this.props.msg && <MessageBanner content={this.props.msg} />}`

But when the message appear, I try to navigate to signup.js, which also have the same

`{this.props.msg && <MessageBanner content={this.props.msg} />}`

The message isn't go away. Or I'm in signup.js page, make the error appear, I click back on the browser, the error did not disappear.

Anyway to clear a state when navigating with react-router?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need correctly setup a "toggle" system to show this error message you have...

Does you MessageBanner have a close button? If so you would want to attach a

```
onClick={this.setState=({toggleErrorMessage: !this.state.toggleErrorMessage})}
```

//on click reverse whatever this.state.toggleErrorMessage currently is...
//so if currently true, after clicking will be false.

Then you could do something more like this.

```
{this.state.toggleErrorMesage ? this.props.msg && <MessageBanner content={this.props.msg} /> : undefined }
```

//if toggleErrorMessage is true, show msg and banner...

Comment: I did a demo for that problem, https://github.com/eldyvoon/react-redux-express-auth

Comment: Based on your code, this {this.props.msg && <MessageBanner content={this.props.msg} />} SHOULD always be showing. You need to setup some toggles to say WHEN this message should show. To your question, if you want to keep the current setup you HAVE. You NEED to create an action to reset this.props.msg.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use Redux, because I fully support redux, however it makes more sense to validate, then set an error message inside the login component, I'll link an example....

https://github.com/GavinThomas1192/motoMechanicMeeKanic/blob/master/App/Containers/SignUpScreen.js